# How to group a table by email and collect order id as comma seperated values in output

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can i get such an output in postgres

```
email       order_ids
xy@cvf.com  1,3,6,7
yz@vgg.com  2,33,10
```

Schema

Orders table

id email

Answer (score 1):

Try Like This

```
 select email,json_Agg(order_ids) from table1 group by email
```

OR

```
select email,string_agg(cast(id as text),',') from table1 group by email
```